# Need formula on how to calculate the work completion days on average

Tags: math, excel-formula, statistics, average, probability

Client give 100 task to employee.
Employee complete 50 task in 1 day
20 task in 2 days
15 task in 3 days
4 task in 4 days
5 taak in 6 days
6 task in 10 days.

Now I want to know on a average how many days employee will take to complete for 1 task

Need formula for this query..

Comment: You'll use two SUM() functions for this.  The math here is (sum of days)/(sum of tasks).  In your example, (1+2+3+4+6+10)/(50+20+15+4+5+6).  that's 26/100, or 0.26 days per task.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming tasks are not completed in parallel (i.e. days are mutually exclusive with respect to completing/working on tasks), average days per task = 0.26:

```
=SUM(B2:B7)/SUM(A2:A7)
```

[image: a) direct ratio]

This is where the solution should terminate - however, I provide a number of checks/alternative approaches which serve to demonstrate (unequivocally) the veracity of the above function...

---

### checks

**check 1**
The same can be derived using the 'weighted average calculation:

```
=SUM((B2:B7/A2:A7)*A2:A7)/SUM(A2:A7)
```

[image: b) weighted avg.]

---

**check 2**
Intuitively, if each task takes ~0.26 days to complete, and there are 100 tasks, then the total duration (days) ~= 26: summing column B gives just that:

[image: sum of days vs. avg. days per task x tasks]

---

**check 3**

If still unconvinced, you can calculate the average days per task for each category/type (i.e. for those that take 1,2,3,.., 10 days to complete):

=B2:B7/A2:A7

[image: check: days per task for task-type]

Then expand these out using sequence / other method:

```
=SEQUENCE(1,A2,G2,0)
```

[image: Check: expanding average days per task per task type]

Again, this yields 0.26 and which should confirm (unequivocally) the veracity of the simple/direct ratio...

Ta